# Error Architecture Framework Adobe Flex 4.0

Tags: apache-flex, architecture, frameworks, flex4

Do you have any example (i.e. URL, code examples, code broilerplates, principles) to describe a good error architecture design for Adobe Flex 4.0?
I am developing an Adobe Flex application for the first time. Do you know of any good examples of error handling frameworks that will allow for the recovery of the application specifically if we are reading multiple files (both graphic files and text files) and one of them is corrupt or the wrong format. I know that there is no global error handling in Flex 3.0, and I have read other posts on error handling that are more specific. I think one post mentioned to have a error handling class and have everything error call that error class. This is one example, I was wondering if there are others or a predefined error architecture framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have any example (i.e. URL, code examples, code broilerplates,
>   principles) to describe a good error architecture design for Adobe
>   Flex 4.0?

Questions that ask for "Good" or "Best practices" are often subjective with many factors in play.  I believe they are impossible to answer.  I'm undecided if this question is "answerable" in the form it takes.  But, I'll try to address some of your specific questions.

> Do you know of any good examples of error handling frameworks that
>   will allow for the recovery of the application specifically if we are
>   reading multiple files (both graphic files and text files) and one of
>   them is corrupt or the wrong format.

What does "Recovery" mean in such situation?  How will you know if the file is in the corrupt or wrong format?  Will an error be thrown?  From what component or class?  From what type?  Will it be an error you create yourself, or something different?

> I know that there is no global error handling in Flex 3.0, and I have
>   read other posts on error handling that are more specific.

That is slightly inaccurate; as Global Error Handling--aka the uncaught Error Exception--is part of the Flash Player. , not part of the Flex Framework.  The [UncaughtErrorEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html) was added in Flash Player 10.1 and AIR 2.  You can build Flex 3 applications that target those players and should be able to make use of those events.

However, at some point, the Flex Application tag, added it's own [uncaughtError](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html#event%3auncaughtError); which is just a layer of abstraction above the Flash Player event.  But, you can use the Flash Player event in a Flex application without this event on the main Application tag.  You'll just have to add the event listeners for such things manually.